# SQL Server 2008 & International Currencies

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, formatting, currency, iso

An application that I've built is used worldwide by our organization and needs to support several different currencies.  SQL Server was doing fine with the 'normal' stuff i.e. the GBP symbol, Euro symbol, but when I introduced the symbol for the Saudi Riyal (ريال SAR), it stores it as question marks.

Client-side is 100% jQuery/javascript working with REST-enabled WCF services.

I ran across something talking about the LocaleID [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlanalysisservices/thread/c2e73827-d760-4704-93d2-28c510fdf785/)

Hoping someone can shed some light on this.

Comment: Please show us the code you tried and doesn't work as expected.

Comment: Not really much code to show here - at least I'm not sure what you're asking to see.  The SQL column is a varchar so that the currency symbols are stored with the amount.  (there's a very long explanation as to why the symbol isn't in a separate column; it just has to be that way)

Comment: alright, JNK's solution to change to nvarchar will it be then.

Comment: sorry, it's actually already nvarchar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Format your strings as `nVarchar`.  If they are in fields in a table, change the datatype.  If they are just formatted on the fly, use the `N` prefix.  `nVarchar` is unicode, which is an expanded international  character set.

Example:

```
SELECT 'ريال'

select N'ريال'
```

On my system, the first shows `????`, the second shows the symbol correctly.

**EDIT**

If the characters were entered as `varchar` you will still have issues.

See example below:

```
DECLARE @t nvarchar(10) = N'ريال'
DECLARE @x nvarchar(10) = 'ريال'

SELECT @t
SELECT @x
```

Comment: This works fine for your example, but putting the N in front of the column name does not seem to work.  i.e. SELECT N [Value] FROM [SomeTable] WHERE [Id] = blahblahblah The datatype of this column is nvarchar.

Comment: @Randall - it looks like it likely an issue with how data was entered into your field(s).  See the edit.

Comment: @Randall: I think the questions are: by what statement(s) did you try to get the value into the nvarchar column, and by what statement(s) do you try to read from it (and display it).

Comment: I know you two are going to want to smack me.  I was correct initially.  1.  The column is varchar (not nvarchar).  2.  I changed it to nvarchar to try it.  3.  I see what you are saying about #2 not working.  4.  I'm really not incompetent!  I just made a mistake about what datatype my column was - this database is very large and easy to get things mixed up.

Comment: The statement getting the value in is a standard sql insert, and getting it out is a standard select.  I still don't understand what code you want to see.  You want to see my DAL?  My stored proc?

Comment: @Randall - if it's `varchar`, you basically lost the invalid characters.  Once you store them in a non-supported datatype, they are lost.  `Varchar` can't store those characters.  Changing to `nvarchar` should fix NEW data, but your old stuff will need to be reinserted or updated.

Comment: This does not work either.  The column was changed to nvarchar, the stored proc changed to nvarchar and a new value was submitted to the database.  I used this to test it: `code` DECLARE @x nvarchar(10)
select @x = value from PropertyValues where Id = 'B29A3580-6FCC-45AD-9E32-0C2E4977E288' 
select @x `code`

Comment: @JNK:  I understand that old values will be invalid.  I just inserted new data after changing the datatype of the column AND the stored proc param.

Comment: @Randall - and what format is the `Value` field in `PropertyValues`?

Comment: ريال (SAR)175.00 --> is this what you mean?   This is what it should be.  I just hit the debugger and this IS what is being passed to the stored proc.

Comment: @Randall - but is it passed as `'ريال(SAR)175.00'` OR `N'ريال(SAR)175.00'`?  I suspect this is the issue.  You may also want to check the datatype of the parameter if it is a param in the stored proc.